# Eclipse Java save Changes on GraphicalEditor on dirty

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

I need to create a plug-in for an existing Eclipse Application that listens to changes in the currently open graphical editor and as soon as the editor is dirty, saves the changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `IEditorPart` for the editor you can use `IEditorPart.addPropertyListener` to listen for the `IEditorPart.PROP_DIRTY` property changing.